# Resizing Images to lower Disk Space Using Plugins

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I'm trying to take existing images and shrink the file size down by resizing to photos to a smaller resolution. I've tried a few methods so far:

1. Simply editing the photo in photoshop and reuploaded, replacing the existing (and larger) file.
2. I tried the [Imsanity](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/imsanity/) plugin and set the options to be less than 1024x1024 and then bulk resized the images without failure (but it did not do the trick).
3. I also tried the [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin, and ran the rebuild without failure (but it did not resize the photos).

Maybe there is a better or a right way to accomplish what I'm doing, but I can't seem to find anything on this issue.

I'm running a Multisite install and WP FTP is not enabled and can't be enabled to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform a combination of things to accomplish a smaller file size. Let me guide you through it.

Firstly, you could [add custom image sizes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) and adjust the dimensions to the very smallest for their purpose. Put the following in your functions file:

```
function my_insert_custom_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
    // get the custom image sizes
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
    // if there are none, just return the built-in sizes
    if ( empty( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) )
        return $sizes;

    // add all the custom sizes to the built-in sizes
    foreach ( $_wp_additional_image_sizes as $id => $data ) {
        // take the size ID (e.g., 'my-name'), replace hyphens with spaces,
        // and capitalise the first letter of each word
        if ( !isset($sizes[$id]) )
            $sizes[$id] = ucfirst( str_replace( '-', ' ', $id ) );
    }

    return $sizes;
}


function custom_image_setup () {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'small', 160, 9999 ); //  small
    add_image_size( 'medium', 300, 9999 ); //  medium
    add_image_size( 'large-cropped', 578, 200, true ); //  cropped
    add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_insert_custom_image_sizes' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_image_setup' );
```

So, `my_insert_custom_image_sizes` adds your custom images to the Media uploader window and I have added a few random sizes in the `custom_image_setup`.

Next, we will need to set the JPEG compression value for each of these sizes. Observe the following:

```
add_filter('jpeg_quality', create_function('$quality', 'return 100;'));

add_action('added_post_meta', 'ad_update_jpeg_quality', 10, 4);

function ad_update_jpeg_quality($meta_id, $attach_id, $meta_key, $attach_meta) {

    if ($meta_key == '_wp_attachment_metadata') {

        $post = get_post($attach_id);

        if ($post->post_mime_type == 'image/jpeg' && is_array($attach_meta['sizes'])) {

            $pathinfo = pathinfo($attach_meta['file']);
            $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
            $dir = $uploads['basedir'] . '/' . $pathinfo['dirname'];

            foreach ($attach_meta['sizes'] as $size => $value) {

                $image = $dir . '/' . $value['file'];
                $resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

                if ($size == 'large') {
                    // set the jpeg quality for 'large' size
                    imagejpeg($resource, $image, 35);
                } elseif ($size == 'medium') {
                    // set the jpeg quality for the 'medium' size
                    imagejpeg($resource, $image, 40);
                } elseif ($size == 'small') {
                    // set the jpeg quality for the 'small' size
                    imagejpeg($resource, $image, 40);
                } elseif ($size == 'large-cropped') {
                    // set the jpeg quality for the 'large-cropped' size
                    imagejpeg($resource, $image, 45);
                } else {
                    // set the jpeg quality for the rest of sizes
                    imagejpeg($resource, $image, 60);
                }

                // or you can skip a particular image size
                // and set the quality for the rest:
                // if ($size == 'splash') continue;

                imagedestroy($resource);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As the comments demonstrate, this part sets the compression value: `imagejpeg($resource, $image, VALUE)`. You will need to play around a little bit and find out what value works best with which image size. I set 60% compression for the rest of images.

The code above affects only newly updated images. If you wish to run a script that will change your existing images, in your plugin folder, add a new folder and create a new php file with this code inside:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Compression JPEG Quality
Plugin URI: http://domain.com
Description: This plugin will change the jpeg image quality according to its size.
Author: Christine
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://domain.com
*/

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'ad_modify_jpeg_quality');

function ad_modify_jpeg_quality() {

    $attachments = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg'
    ));

    if (empty($attachments)) return;

    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();

    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

        $attach_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment->ID);
        if (!is_array($attach_meta['sizes'])) break;

        $pathinfo = pathinfo($attach_meta['file']);
        $dir = $uploads['basedir'] . '/' . $pathinfo['dirname'];

        foreach ($attach_meta['sizes'] as $size => $value) {

            $image = $dir . '/' . $value['file'];
            $resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

                    if ($size == 'large') {
                        // set the jpeg quality for 'large' size
                        imagejpeg($resource, $image, 35);
                    } elseif ($size == 'medium') {
                        // set the jpeg quality for the 'medium' size
                        imagejpeg($resource, $image, 40);
                    } elseif ($size == 'small') {
                        // set the jpeg quality for the 'small' size
                        imagejpeg($resource, $image, 40);
                    } elseif ($size == 'large-cropped') {
                        // set the jpeg quality for the 'large-cropped' size
                        imagejpeg($resource, $image, 45);
                    } else {
                        // set the jpeg quality for the rest of sizes
                        imagejpeg($resource, $image, 60);
                    }

            imagedestroy($resource);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Finally, add the [WP Smush.it](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-smushit/) plugin which will bring down the file sizes even further.

A few notes to consider:

- None of this affects PNG file uploads. Your only option with this file format is to add a plugin that will convert PNG to JPEG however this will mean that transparency will not work.  Another desperate solution would be to have all PNG files converted to PNG 8-bit file format which is limited to 256 colours. However, that would take your uploads back to the 90's.
- The compression will not affect the `Full size` size option. This is the original file upload. If you are running a multiple author site and want to avoid your authors adding this filesize, you could add a filter to remove this file size from the drop down list.
- These codes have been tested and functions fine with both Wordpress v3.4.2 and v3.5

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp-smush it plugin 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-smushit/

It reduces the size of images